# Erro Busca Banco de Dados PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou fazendo uma página que busca informações em tabelas de um banco de dados MySQL, a conexão tá beleza, mas está aparecendo dois erros :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in **/home/----/public_html/pesquisa.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in **/home/----/public_html/pesquisa.php on line 15

Meu código php está assim:

```
<?php

include ('conecta.php');

$pesquisa_rapida = $_POST["txtpesquisa"];
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nm_candidato LIKE '%".$pesquisa_rapida."%'");
$sql->bind_param("s",$pesquisa_rapida);

$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$result=$sql->affected_rows;

if ($result > 0){

        while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
           $nm_candidato = $linha['nm_candidato'];        
           $nm_candidatura = $linha['nm_candidatura']; 
           $ds_cargo = $linha['ds_cargo'];
           echo "<strong>Nome: </strong>".@$nm_candidato;
           echo "<br /><br />"; 
           echo "<strong>Nome Candidatura: </strong>".@$nm_candidatura;
           echo "<br /><br />"; 
           echo "<strong>Cargo: </strong>".@$ds_cargo;
           echo "<br /><br />"; 
        }
}
else {
    echo "Desculpe, nada foi encontrado";
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código faz o bind de um valor porém nenhum placholder(`?`) foi passado na consulta, também os coringas(`%` ou `_`) na variável com termo a ser pesquisado e não na sql. O segundo erro é causado pelo primeiro para corrigir isso e vitar sql injection troque a variável por uma interrogação:

Mude:

```
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nm_candidato LIKE '%".$pesquisa_rapida."%'");
```

Para:

```
$pesquisa_rapida = '%'. $_POST["txtpesquisa"] .'%';
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE nm_candidato LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$pesquisa_rapida);
$res = $sql->get_result();
$result=$sql->affected_rows;

while($linha = $res->fetch_assoc()){
   //demais linhas
}
```

Comment: modifiquei  mas agora está dando esse erro: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/irbpe586/public_html/pesquisa.php on line 7

Comment: @Sarah como vc colocou? o erro diz que a consulta falhou, table que contém os dados chama `tabela` mesmo?

Comment: kkk q burrice, ñ mesmo! arrumei o nome da tabela, mas tá dando outro erro : Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /home/irbpe586/public_html/pesquisa.php on line 15

Comment: @Sarah vc precisa passar a conexão como primeiro argumento em `mysqli_query()`

Comment: $pesquisa_rapida = '%'. $_POST["txtpesquisa"] .'%';
$sql=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM resultado_votacao_candidato_zona_eleicaomunicipal WHERE nm_candidato LIKE ?");

Comment: como assim, a conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: @Sarah sim, deve ficar mais ou menos assim `mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli, $sql)`

Comment: eu coloquei um include no início que direciona para um php q está fazendo a conexão com o banco

Comment: @Sarah me enganei já corrijo

Comment: `<?php

$host='host.com.br';
$user='user';
$pass='******';
$database='irbpe586_appirb';

$mysqli= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
 die ('Falha na conexao com o banco de dados. Erro: '.mysqli_connect_errno());
 exit();
}

?>`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37667/discussion-between-sarah-and-rray).

Comment: @Sarah corrigido.

Comment: coloquei assim mas ñ funcionou

Comment: while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli, $sql)){

Comment: ta dando esse erro: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in /home/irbpe586/public_html/pesquisa.php on line 15

Comment: o erro é no mysqli_fetch_array(), fiz assim: mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli, $sql)), mas não deu certo

Comment: @Sarah eu troquei o `strore_result` pelo `get_result()`

Comment: já consegui coloquei assim: while ($dados=  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

Answer (score 1):

Muda a linha:

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Para

```
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Porque você não usa num_rows?

Comment: como assim?ñ entendi

Comment: como eu uso num_rows?

Comment: eu  mudei a linha deu esse erro: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, integer given in /home/irbpe586/public_html/irbapp/pesquisa.php on line 17

Comment: ele está pesquisando e encontrando os dados o problema é só esse na hora de mostrar os demais dados da tabela cujo dado foi encontrado

Comment: Eu uso num rows para contar registros.
Vou refazer seu código:

Comment: Você já resolveu! :)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada pela ajuda de todos. Ficou assim:

```
<?php

    include ('conecta.php');

    $pesquisa = '"%'. $_POST["txtpesquisa"] .'%"';

    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
     if (!$connection) {
     echo ("Erro ao conectar!"); 
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela "
            . "WHERE nome LIKE ".$pesquisa."";
    $result =  mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Query invalida");
    }

    while ($linha=  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    if ($result > 0){
        echo "Nome: $linha[nome]<br />"; 
        echo "<hr>";

    }
    else {
        echo "nada foi encontrado";
    }
    }
   ?>
```